# Contenteditable--change background color when editing

Tags: javascript, html, css

When editing an element with the contenteditable attribute I want the background color of that element to change colors. For example, if the element background color was dark grey I would want it to turn white while editing the element and then reset back to dark grey when done editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
[contenteditable="true"] {
    background-color: grey;
}

[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dopernicus/KSGXP/).

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this.

```css
[contenteditable]:focus {
    background: #fff;
}
```